# List of SharePoint development tools

Tags: development, tools

What tools do you consider essential in your SharePoint development toolkit?

**One answer per tool please** so the community can vote!

Answer (score 52):

[SharePoint Manager](http://spm.codeplex.com/) is a SharePoint object model explorer. It enables you to browse every site on the local farm and view every property. It also enables you to change the properties (at your own risk). This is a very powerfull tool for developers that like to know what the SharePoint holds of secrets.

Answer (score 40):

[SPDisposeCheck](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SPDisposeCheck) - to check for any dispose mistakes that could result in a memory leak.

Good to have hooked up to a build target as a post-build step so that the build fails if any problems are found.

Comment: I would now recommend SPCop instead. It already includes SPDisposeCheck. This tool is free to use and contains a lot of rules that check your code for common mistakes

Answer (score 35):

[U2U CAML Query Builder](http://www.u2u.net/res/Tools/CamlQueryBuilder.aspx) - who in the SharePoint world can live without this one! It helps you avoid commoin CAML mistakes.

Answer (score 31):

[WSPBuilder](http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com) - for an easier, faster and more troublefree way to create new SharePoint solutions/features.

Comment: WSPBuilder is essential for building SP 2007 apps, but I very dislike the 2010 version, compared to Visual Studio native SharePoint projects. Also good to know, [CKSDev](http://cksdev.codeplex.com/) provides a project template that import WSP Builder projects (very useful for migrating projects)

Comment: Yep, CKSDev is the way to go now. I think this thread is already too old. It might give false impression to the novice SharePoint developers. Many tools mentioned here are not essential anymore because some better replacements appeared.

Answer (score 30):

Can't do any serious development/debugging without [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)

It's a great tool for examining all HTTP(s) traffic of your apps.

Answer (score 26):

My favorite ULS Viewer:  http://ulsviewer.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 23):

**[Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843)!** Useful in so many ways:

- Editing HTML and CSS in-browser and on the fly
- Ability to see which CSS rules are active and work with the box model
- JavaScript console and debugging support (excellent for jQuery)
- Net tab for seeing server requests and download performance

Answer (score 23):

I've found **[.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/)** (now from RedGate) to be an indispensable tool when developing, and with SharePoint in particular.  In some cases it has saved me from spinning wheels when it is clearly a "bug" or "feature" in the SP codebase, but it most cases it has just been invaluable from a learning perspective (oh, that's how that works!)

Comment: The Reflector is actually my SP documentation!

Comment: If buting Reflector is an issue, [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) is a free alternative. Not as complete as reflector, but efficient to  explore some obscure sharePoint components

Comment: For completeness there's also [DotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) by JetBrains (of Resharper) and [JustDecompiler](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx) by Telerik

Answer (score 16):

Maybe not SharePoint specific, but I don't write code without [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/index.html#). Countless ways it improves productivity.

Answer (score 15):

I use IE8's Developer Tools whenever I work with JavaScript, CSS or HTML in SharePoint.

Comment: the DOM inspector is no where near as accurate as Firebug so I tend to avoid it as it's misleading.

Answer (score 15):

[PowerShell](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/technologies/management/powershell/download.mspx)! I use PowerShell more and more for small POC's where I would normally use console apps. Also for automation PowerShell is a great tool!

Answer (score 14):

@glapointe's [STSADM custom extensions](http://blog.falchionconsulting.com/index.php/category/stsadm-commands/). The tools rock, and also looking at his code and seeing how he writes the functions helps you understand the API too!

Answer (score 12):

It asked for only one product per answer but I will group a couple as they work together.

[NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/) - for your unit testing.   I also use MSTest but find NUnit has less clutter (VS2010 removes this for MSTest)

[TestDriven.Net](http://www.testdriven.net/) - great tool for running the tests and include the open source version of NCover for your coverage needs.

Answer (score 12):

Another one that's not really a tool but nevertheless very handy; in my quick launch bar I always add a Shortcut and a Toolbar to the 12 hive:

> C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\12

Answer (score 11):

## Development

### Main

- Visual Studio

  - [Visual Studio 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us) (SharePoint 2010), currently in Release candidate version
  - [Visual Studio 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us) (SharePoint 2010) with [service pack 1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23691)
  - [Visual Studio 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2008-editions) (SharePoint 2007)
- SharePoint Designer

  - [SharePoint Designer 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24309) (SharePoint 2010)
  - [SharePoint Designer 2007](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21581) (SharePoint 2007)

### Visual Studio extensions

- [CKSDev](http://cksdev.codeplex.com/)
- [WSPBuilder](http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com/), for Sharepoint 2007 (not reliable and quite useless with SharePoint 2010)

### SDK

- [SharePoint 2010 Reference: Software Development Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=12323)

### Companion tools

- [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx)
- [SharePoint Manager 2010](http://spm.codeplex.com/)

## Administration

### TODO

Comment: Hey Steve, I've merged the questions, unlocked this question, and edited so it isn't version specific. I think you should be good to go! :)

Answer (score 10):

TypeMock http://typemock.com

it's the only way to write unit tests for sharepoint. Somthing we all should be doing.

http://www.qualitysharepoint.com/2009/03/options-for-unit-testing-sharepoint.html

Answer (score 8):

For SharePoint 2010 Development:

[SharePoint 2010 Developer Dashboard Visualizer](http://devdashvis.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 7):

I'm suprised no one has brought up [STSDev](http://stsdev.codeplex.com/) from codeplex. I like the way it sets up the project and set ups all the files and build tasks. Worth a look.

Answer (score 7):

[SPTraceView](http://sptraceview.codeplex.com/) is awesome for seeing errors that occur on SharePoint server, especially if it's your dev box as they happen via the System Tray! Also when you double click on tray it shows the exceptions...rather than you opening whole ugly ULS log ;-)

Answer (score 7):

Sure fiddler is good, but Visual RoundTrip Analyzer (VRTA) gives you a nice graphical illustration and can also help you with advice in solving the problems.
It has issues regarding virtual environments though, but a great tool never the less (thanx Spence for introducing it to me:-) [download VRTA](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=119F3477-DCED-41E3-A0E7-D8B5CAE893A3&displaylang=en)

Comment: VRTA is awesome, great for finding and analyzing your bottlenecks

Answer (score 7):

The content [deployment wizard](http://spdeploymentwizard.codeplex.com/): 
The SharePoint Content Deployment Wizard is a tool for SharePoint 2007 which provides the means to deploy the following content:

- site collections
- webs
- lists
- folders
- list items (including files)

Answer (score 6):

Slight bias here. But I can't build SharePoint Lists, Content Types, Site Columns and Module files without [SPSource](http://spsource.codeplex.com/) written by myself (@jthake) and @richfinn!

Answer (score 6):

DebugView from Sysinternals/now Technet combined with System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine, System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert etc is very good especially in events or workflows where you cannot do trace.

Answer (score 5):

[SharePoint Skinner](http://www.elumenotion.com/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=94) for creating CSS styles and themes for your site visually

Answer (score 5):

I recommend using **[VSeWSS 1.3 March 2009 CTP](http://www.microsoft.com/DownLoads/details.aspx?familyid=FB9D4B85-DA2A-432E-91FB-D505199C49F6&displaylang=en)** and hopefully RTW soon.

Comment: The question asks for one answer per tool so we can vote and see which ones are popular. Please add any tools that don't already exist as separate answers and when you have enough rep vote for the ones you value!

Comment: My bad...  I will correct it.

Comment: Thanks! Downvote removed. BTW think I read somewhere that there won't be an RTM of VSeWSS 1.3. Pretty sure the SP dev team are entirely focussed on the SP2010/VS2010 integration.

Comment: Thats good to know...  I possed this question on the SharePoint forums and Paul Andrew commented that it was not going to be available until October 2009.  You might just be right.  Below is a link to the post.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/b0987b13-a8c5-47d7-a242-61deef134f6b

Answer (score 5):

[Microsoft Live Mesh](http://www.mesh.com/) is a great tool to handle all your other tools. I've set up a folder that I have all my tools in and then use Live Mesh to have these tools synchronized into my VM's and other machines. As soon as I add or update a tool, they are all "copied" to my other machines.

Answer (score 5):

[TypeMock Isolator](http://learn.typemock.com/) - essential if you are doing unit testing and need to fake out the calls to SharePoint

Comment: Thanks Woody. We already have TypeMock here: http://www.sharepointoverflow.com/questions/81/what-tools-are-essential-for-every-sharepoint-developer/102#102 It's turning into a longer list than I expected...

Answer (score 5):

Ehm, noone said MetaMan yet? Doint BDC by hand is such a pain... MetaMan is the best tool out there. And now also web based. (ok Nick you can cough up a with a dev license now ;-)
Nah seriously, its an expensive tool, and the licensing model sux (for devs at consultancy companies that has lots of different customers) but the tool is top notch and saved me more times than i care to remember from doing tedious XML

Answer (score 5):

What? Noone said SQL Server Profiler yet? How the heck do you guys find out what goes on behind the scenes without it? :-)

Especially good when you are after better performance. A quick profiler run will find those pesky SharePoint "specialities" in .NET like using foreach instead of for loops, or the difference in performance of doing SPContext.Current.List.ItemCount and SPContext.Current.List.Items.Count, finding deadlocks, timeouts etc

Answer (score 5):

I use sharegate to deploy sites from DEV to QA to Prod and Prod to QA to Dev.

http://www.share-gate.com

From their website :

> sharegate is a light yet powerful tool
>   to compare and synchronize your
>   SharePoint environments in only three
>   steps. It quickly detects the
>   differences between your sites and
>   allows you to send your chosen
>   selections to your desired destination
>   from anywhere in your organization.
>   Our tool accelerates your SharePoint
>   deployments by significantly reducing
>   the time consuming manual process. The
>   power of sharegate resides in its
>   simplicity and its cost. We all agree
>   that we need a simple tool for
>   SharePoint synchronization.

Comment: @Guillaume Roy: Please edit your answer to clearly disclose that this is your company's product. Spam is not tolerated on SharePoint Overflow. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 4):

[SP|CAF](http://www.spcaf.com/) : SharePoint Code Analysis Framework

Essential tool to ensure SharePoint code quality. SPCAF analyses SharePoint code from .wsp and .app files and checks all contained code incl. XML, ASPX, JS, CSS for correctness, best practices etc.

It creates dependency Graphs, calculates code metrics and creates an inventory.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

http://smtp4dev.codeplex.com/ - "Sets up a dummy SMTP server. Sits in the system tray and does not deliver the received messages. The received messages can be quickly viewed, saved and the source/structure inspected. Useful for testing/debugging software that generates email."

Perfect for small develop environments.

Answer (score 3):

I would say a Virtual PC/Environment is essential

Answer (score 3):

I also found [CAML.NET IntelliSense](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/camlintellisense/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=2212) to be very valuable.  This has saved me alot of time.

Answer (score 3):

HyperV! I love doing dev work on my pumped up 2008 server where i can spawn as many virtual servers as i need with performance that leaves VMWare in the dust!

Comment: Moreover, Windows 8 is now shipped with Hyper-V, which avoid users to work on server OS (for their daily job).

Answer (score 3):

Spencer Harbar's [Application Pool Manager](http://www.harbar.net/articles/apm.aspx), for speedy and specfic App Pool resets.

Answer (score 3):

I use [SPVisualDev](http://spvisualdev.codeplex.com/). Integrates with wspbuilder and now apparently allows remote development (did not try this yet).

Answer (score 3):

Gallio and MBUnit testing frameworks

Answer (score 3):

SysInternal's (now Microsoft) [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) is essential for troubleshooting security and other problems related to access to the file system, registry etc. Not SharePoint specific, but I find myself using it in combination with SharePoint on a frequent basis.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend the [SharePoint Software Factory](http://spsf.codeplex.com) which not only allows you to develop for SharePoint 2007 and 2010 from either VS2008 or VS2010, but also supports you with wizards to create the usual SharePoint artefacts.

Have a look at the video on the codeplex page.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SharePoint Stack Exchange! We require disclosure of any affiliation with products or websites. Please see [May I promote products or websites I am affiliated with here?](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion) for guidelines. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Yet another great **decompiler** for investigation of inner working of SharePoint - **[dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/)**

**Main features**

- Decompiling .NET 1.0-4.5 assemblies to C#
- Support for .dll, .exe, .zip, .vsix, .nupkg, and .winmd files
- Quick jump to a type, assembly, symbol, or type member
- Effortless navigation to symbol declarations,implementations, derived and base symbols,and more
- Accurate search for symbol usages with advanced presentation of search results
- Overview of inheritance chains
- Support for downloading code from source servers
- Syntax highlighting
- Complete keyboard support

and dotPeek is free!

Main Window
[image]

Answer (score 2):

On the nerdy side, but when Reflector gives up due to obfuscation, and you just *need* to know what happens behind the scene, enter **ildasm.exe**
True you need to be able to read IM language, but its pretty self explanatory, and have helped me many times. For example when i wanted to know what exactly happend behind the scenes when you use -force (bad bad practice!) in stsadm.exe operations (bonus info: -force basicly swallows *all* exceptions, so you never will see those *other* code issues your callouts or similar had)

Answer (score 2):

One app, that allows me to navigate the SharePoint folders and having shortcuts to them, walk in and out of WSP's, quickly view the content of the files etc is [Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com).

Using Windows Explorer and walking down into the 12-hive, right-click, select open with really takes to much precious time. Using Total Commander I have shortcuts to the different folders in the 12-hive and then uses the builtin quick search to find the file and the builtin viewer program.

This is one tool I can't live without, and is the first thing I install on all machines (if I don't use [Live Mesh](http://www.mesh.com/), which contains my Total Commander installation folder).

Answer (score 2):

I like [Crimson Editor](http://www.crimsoneditor.com/) as an alternative to notepad. Lightweight (no waiting time to start like visual studio), tabbed interface, macros, "column mode".

Great for quickly creating xml files, csv files, or transforming an xml file into a set of c# lines (using macros)

Answer (score 2):

Cruise Control .NET to allow nightly builds of your SharePoint solutions.

Answer (score 2):

[Web Development Helper](http://projects.nikhilk.net/WebDevHelper) or some similar tool, to track the communication between the browser and the SharePoint Server.
Especially usefull when developing with Ajax, jQuery, Silverlight, or any other RIA technology.

Answer (score 2):

[MOSS BDC Design Studio](http://www.simego.com). Cheaper than Metaman but I found to have all the tools I need to create ADFs for the Business Data Catalogue.

Answer (score 2):

a bit of shameless self-promotion, but [SharePoint InlineSiteSettings](http://inlinesitesettings.codeplex.com/) is a small jQuery script I put on CodePlex that saves a developer (or admin) a significant amount time by shortening the navigation paths and limiting the amount of mouse clicks required to get to a particular admin page in SharePoint. It's all about keeping the momentum going :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to demonstrate a bias too, but then, I do lots with SharePoint search and I'm always using it:

[SearchCoder](http://www.codeplex.com/MOSSSearchCoder)

Helps you write and quickly test search queries.

Answer (score 2):

Moss Query Tool - Excellent tool to test search queries against the MOSS search database. The application helps you build queries as well.

I can't seem to find the download link anywhere but after a quick Google search, I found this tool [SharePointSearchServ](http://www.codeplex.com/SharePointSearchServ) which apparently replaces MOSS Query Tool.

Answer (score 2):

Fxcop for static code analysis, in case you are using a VS prof edition

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create an on the go, Standalone SP virtual server, use 'VM Player'. It's free and easy to use :D!!

Answer (score 2):

[Imtech Fields Explorer](http://imtech.codeplex.com/releases/view/17330)

Great tool for exporting content types, site columns and lists definition in XML; available on Codeplex.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very relevant thread from a few years ago before 2010 was released:  [List of SharePoint development tools](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/81/list-of-sharepoint-2007-wss-3-0-development-tools)

Answer (score 2):

**User Profile Service application Debugging:**

if you couldn't set up User Profiles service application in the correct way, you might not get to the actual error straightaway during the sync. The right way to get the actual error message is to use the Synchronization service manager (MIIS Client) and debug User Profile service application.

Path to MIIS Client can be found at:

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\14.0\Synchronization
>   Service\UIShell\miisclient.exe

Answer (score 2):

**[LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/)** - free development tool for learning and testing Language Integrated Query (LINQ) against SQL, ODATA, or an Entity Framework solution

### Purpose

Great way to learn to Query the [SharePoint List Data Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798339.aspx) with LinqPad

Main Window
[image]

### References

- SharePoint 2010 REST interface on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798339.aspx)
- Learn to Query the SharePoint List Data Service with LinqPad [article](http://www.mssharepointtips.com/tip.asp?id=1179&page=2)
- Using LINQ to SharePoint on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee535491%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

[CAML Designer for SharePoint 2013](http://biwug-web.sharepoint.com/SitePages/Caml_designer.aspx)

- Build CAML queries for single lists
- Build queries that can be executed with SPSiteDataQuery
- Get code snippets for the server-side object model, the .NET client-side object model, the JavaScript client-side object model and last but not least code snippets when working with REST.

Answer (score 2):

[VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) - the poor man's virtual machine maker (an alternative to HyperV).

Answer (score 1):

A tool usefull for sites content migration: [WssAnalyzeFeatures](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WssAnalyzeFeatures)

This tool allows to verify if the feature definition files for all installed features are present on the file system. Also allows to verify if the features used in site collections an sites are installed on the server.
In addition it can create a checklist file which can be used to verify if a server has all features installed required to act as destination for a content deployment job of an existing sitecollection.

Usage:

WssAnalyzeFeatures -url http://server:port

More about it here: [WssAnalyzeFeatures](http://blogs.technet.com/stefan%5Fgossner/archive/2008/04/11/deep-dive-into-the-sharepoint-content-deployment-and-migration-api-part-6.aspx)

Comment: These tools already exist as answers. Please vote them up instead of adding another answer so we can see their popularity.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few helpful tools I use:

ULS Viewer (to view ULS Logs) -http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ULSViewer/

SPCAMLEditor (to edit XLST) -http://spcamleditor.codeplex.com/

Here's a list of other useful tools:

https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/devwiki/articles/Pages/SharePoint-Dev-Toolbelt.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I use only SharePointDesigner2010 and InfoPath2010. These are good too.

Answer (score 0):

[SharePoint Feature Admin Tool](https://featureadmin.codeplex.com/) - for taming and nuking rogue features orphaned during caffeine fueled development sessions.

Along with the following handy powershell commands to force delete broken features.

```
Get-SPFeature | ? { $_.Scope -eq $null }
Get-SPFeature | ? { !$_.Scope } | % { $_.Delete() }
```