# What third party development tools are available for SharePoint 2010?

Tags: tools

What is a list of third party tools available to support SharePoint 2010 developers?

**One answer per tool please so the community can vote.**

Comment: please make this kind of open questions with several answers Community Wiki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been up several times before

For SP2007, which still applies for most tools

[List of SharePoint development tools](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/81/what-tools-are-essential-for-every-sharepoint-2007-wss-3-0-developer)

The most important 3rd party tool is without doubt Community Kit for SharePoint [CKS:DEV](http://cksdev.codeplex.com/) that extends the Visual Studio Studio integrated tools for SharePoint development.

Answer (score 1):

The most important (for me) would be WSPBuilder: http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com/

Can't do proper Sharepoint development without it. Well, can, but it will be much slower.

Comment: how do you compare the "Package" function in VS2010 to WSPBuilder?

Comment: Most functions of VS2010 make WSP Builder obsolete. Still I like it for quick access to the 'Attack to IIS' instead of pushing F5, which retracts and redeploys your solution. For most other things you don't really need WSP Builder anymore for SP2010 development. Can't do SP2007 development without it though.

Answer (score 0):

The Imtech Create Page Layout Extenstion (SP2010) can be put to good use also: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/990bd0c8-a55b-4643-a35d-88136594c3d9

Off-course, most of the [Imtech](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/site/search?f%5b0%5d.Type=SearchText&f%5b0%5d.Value=imtech&x=0&y=0) solutions are very good for Sharepoint development.