# What are all supporting tools commonly used by SharePoint 2010 development?

Tags: development, third-party-software, tools

1. CAML Builder
2. SharePoint Designer 2010
3. CKS Development tool edition(server)
4. SharePoint Manager 2010

These are the tool which is used to make SharePoint development simpler. Can someone tell is there any other tool which is used for SharePoint development?

*Only for Sharepoint 2010!
*I am not looking only third party even MS tool also.

Comment: I've convered this to a community wiki.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I very often use [ULS Viewer](https://web.archive.org/web/20140430042223/http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com:80/ULSViewer) ([more info](https://web.archive.org/web/20160216051021/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/opal/archive/2009/12/22/uls-viewer-for-sharepoint-2010-troubleshooting.aspx)) from microsoft. Very useful tool to quickly find the cause of an error. I have even created a keyboard shortcut, and when I see an error on page, I copy correlation, run viewer and filter events by correlation.

[.NET Reflector](https://web.archive.org/web/20130402205905/http://www.reflector.net/) or free analog [IL SPY](https://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx). Before SharePoint development I used this tools very rarely, but for sharepoint sometimes its extremely useful.

[CAML.NET Intellisense](https://web.archive.org/web/20120422204502/http://www.sharepointarchitects.us:80/johnholliday/post/2010/11/03/caml-net-intellisense-for-sharepoint-2010/) also makes your development a little bit easier.

You can also check this [question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/81/list-of-sharepoint-development-tools) from related, most of tools for sharepoint 2007 still applicable for sharepoint 2010.

Answer (score 4):

[Stramit SharePoint Caml Viewer](http://spcamlviewer.codeplex.com/). This tool allow to write CAML by hands. CAML builder allow only UI using. It's important in case of using  and hidden fields.

[ULS Viewer](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ULSViewer) - very usefull log viewing tool.

Answer (score 4):

[SPDisposeCheck](http://www.fewlines4biju.com/2011/08/spdisposecheck-for-sharepoint-2010.html)

Also a very good tool used for checking dispose objects

Answer (score 2):

I rely on [Powershell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee539977.aspx) quite a bit.

(It's not third party per se as it's made by Microsoft, but since you included SPD I thought I might get away with it.)

Comment: Thanks, I am not looking only third party even MS tool also.

Answer (score 2):

I still use [WSP Builder](http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com/), not for building WSPs, but because of the

1. Copy to GAC
2. Recycle app pools,
3. Recycle services timer, and
4. Attach to IIS app pools

functionality that it has on it's menu.

Comment: This is all built into CKS:Dev for Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Yeah... I can't seem to find the Copy to GAC function though, which is a biggie for me. Also I tend to get exceptions when trying to attach to processes (NullReferenceException at CKS.Dev.VisualStudio.SharePoint.Environment.ProcessUtilities.AttachToProcessByName)

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio 2010 is critical for building portable, scaleable, testable and maintainable sp code solutions.

I second the importance of powershell and. Net reflector/il spy

Also, I've started to work with jefs, it's a tool on codeplex that a colleague of mine wrote. It simplifies javascript dev in sharepoint and it allows you to easily include libraries like jquery libs

Answer (score 2):

[SharePoint Software Factory](http://spsf.codeplex.com/) is best for learning as well to speed-up your work.