# How do I get started with developing a custom web service in SharePoint?

Tags: web-services

How would I get started with developing a custom web service in SharePoint?

Are there are tools I could use, or tutorials that would help me?

Comment: Are you kidding me - the top ** 5 ** results in Google for "custom web service in sharepoint" tell you exactly what you need.

Comment: @Ryan: *ahem* : http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/607/is-it-ok-to-ask-easily-google-able-questions-like-what-is-feature-stapling

Comment: Yes I know, which is why I answered. Excuse the frustration but it had to have taken more effort for the OP to ask the damn question than to put the most obvious phrase into google and pick any one of the top 5 answers - any one at all. No google foo required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below are a few links you may find useful. Unfortunately this is a very broad question, so it isn't possible to include all the details here.

**Tutorials**

MSDN Walkthrough for a basic web service:

[Creating a Custom ASP.NET Web Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms464040.aspx)

A SharePoint 2007 web service walkthrough (with downloadable code):

[Creating a Custom Web Service for SharePoint](http://www.walisystems.com/articles/SPS/uplservice/v1/creating%20a%20custom%20web%20service.htm)

A SharePoint 2010 WCF service walkthrough (with downloadable code):

[Custom WCF Services in SharePoint 2010](http://blog.sharepointbits.com/2010/04/custom-wcf-services-in-sharepoint-2010_17.html)

**Tools**

The most important tool is obviously going to be Visual Studio. I haven't heard of any tools to specifically help you with this project, although there's a generally useful list of SharePoint Development tools here:

[List of SharePoint development tools](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/81/list-of-sharepoint-2007-wss-3-0-development-tools)

Answer (score 4):

How about ["Walkthrough: Creating a Custom ASP.NET (ASMX) Web Service in SharePoint 2010"](http://msmvps.com/blogs/windsor/archive/2011/11/04/walkthrough-creating-a-custom-asp-net-asmx-web-service-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

See [Arjun Chakraborty blog post](http://www.thesharepointblog.net/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=815f255a-d0ef-4258-be2a-28487dc9975c&ID=64), except the part where you push web.config with deploy to the hive and overwrite the existing ISAPI web.config. Edit your config into the ISAPI web.config.